# while I want to put params to url to GET some data it puts % instead of > ? Angular 9

Tags: angular, http, url, get, angular9

I want to use `http.get` method to get some data in response, but when I want to put a `>` it puts % instead.
my code is:

```
let search = "class>"+`${this.class};&city=${this.city}`;
```

and my service method is:

```
 getExtByClassAndCity( page_size: number, page: number, search: string,direction: string,order_by: string) {
    const params = {
      order_by,
      direction,
      page_size,
      search,
      page,
    }
    return this.http.get<any>(`${env.apiURL}sips?`+`order_by=`+params.order_by+`&direction=`+params.direction+`&page_size=`+params.page_size
    +`&search=`+params.search+`&page=`+params.page_size);
  }
```

and the send url is

```
sips?order_by=ext_sips.extension&direction=desc&page_size=5&search=class%3Exxxx;&city=&page=5
```

I mean this % in the class param.
Please tell me how can I print `class>xxxx` instead of `class%3Exxxx`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a HttpParams object and add your parameters to it like that:

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('order_by', order_by).set('direction', direction); // also for the other parameters
```

Then don't construct the whole URL yourself, but add the HttpParams to the *get* call

```
return this.http.get<any>(`${env.apiURL}sips`,{params});
```

Comment: when I put like `return this.http.get<any>(`${env.apiURL}sips?${params}`);` it gives me an error: `sips?[object%20Object]`

Comment: `{params}` should be a separate parameter to the get function. I updated the answer, so that the string actually closes.

Comment: You are right, I changed the method code to:
 `const params2 = new HttpParams().set('order_by', order_by).set('direction',           direction).set('page_size', page_size.toString())
    .set('search', search).set('page', page.toString()); 
    return this.http.get<any>(`${env.apiURL}sips?${params2}`);` 

and it works fine. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

Guys this `%` does not make any change for response to the server.
And if you see I put page_size instead of page at the end of the request. Now it should return an object of array 6 but it only returns 1 row and I don't know why!
If you know why please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a literal ">" character in a URI, so it gets percent-encoded. See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#percent-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

My answer for my first answer's question, it was because I was plus the pageIndex to 1 then I sent this pageIndex as page in the URL, but my backend page starts from 0 not 1 so when I had 6 rows it shows me only the final row in the second page (because the page_size is equal to 5).
It's because I fetch data by pagination from server.